# Referencing JSON object in view of my node.js app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following JSON parsed object and I'm trying to render `given_title` of `list` property, for example but not sure how to deal with this list number `'890245271'` in between.

```
{ status: 1,
  complete: 1,
  list: 
   { '890245271': 
      { item_id: '890245271',
        resolved_id: '890245271',
        given_url: 'http://davidwalsh.name/open-graph-data-nodejs',
        given_title: 'Get Open Graph Data with Node.js',

        ... } 
   },
  error: null,
  search_meta: { search_type: 'normal' },
  since: 1444659949 }
```

My attempt is this but it complains about this number.

```
<% data.list.890245271.forEach(function(item) { %>
        <p><%= item.given_title %></p>
<% }); %>
```

**UPDATE**

The marked similar answer does not entirely address my problem.
Mine is not JSON. It's parsed to object.

Comment: What templating engine is that?

Comment: What's "parsed object"? What interface does it expose?

Comment: Well JSON's properties are string. And to access and render in view, you parse it to javascript object. My question was marked as duplicate but that question addresses referencing JSON.